# Adding an additional change event trigger with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'd like to add an additional change trigger with jquery at the end of this function.  Currently, the only change condition is `.keyup` at the end, but I'd like to add `.mouseup` as well.  I know there's a way to do this with `.on`, but I haven't been able to figure out a way.  Maybe a syntax error.

```
                    var ButtonVal =  null
var txt= ""
$("input.search").change(function() {
    txt = $("input.search").val();

    if (txt) { function search(){

          if (ButtonVal == null) {

         $("#WebPartWPQ5").find("tr.ms-itmhover:not(:Contains("+txt+"))").hide();
         $("#WebPartWPQ5").find("tr.ms-itmhover:Contains("+txt+")").show();



         $("#WebPartWPQ6").find("tr.ms-itmhover:not(:Contains("+txt+"))").hide();
         $("#WebPartWPQ6").find("tr.ms-itmhover:Contains("+txt+")").show();


         $("#WebPartWPQ4").find("tr.ms-itmhover:not(:Contains("+txt+"))").hide();
         $("#WebPartWPQ4").find("tr.ms-itmhover:Contains("+txt+")").show();


         $("#WebPartWPQ7").find("tr.ms-itmhover:not(:Contains("+txt+"))").hide();
         $("#WebPartWPQ7").find("tr.ms-itmhover:Contains("+txt+")").show();


         $("#WebPartWPQ2").find("tr.ms-itmhover:not(:Contains("+txt+"))").hide();
         $("#WebPartWPQ2").find("tr.ms-itmhover:Contains("+txt+")").show();


         $("#WebPartWPQ8").find("tr.ms-itmhover:not(:Contains("+txt+"))").hide();
         $("#WebPartWPQ8").find("tr.ms-itmhover:Contains("+txt+")").show();
        }
                    if(ButtonVal != null){
        $("#WebPartWPQ5").find("tr.ms-itmhover:not(:Contains("+txt+"):Contains("+ButtonVal+"))").hide();
        $("#WebPartWPQ5").find("tr.ms-itmhover:Contains("+txt+"):Contains("+ButtonVal+")").show();      

         $("#WebPartWPQ6").find("tr.ms-itmhover:not(:Contains("+txt+"):Contains("+ButtonVal+"))").hide();
        $("#WebPartWPQ6").find("tr.ms-itmhover:Contains("+txt+"):Contains("+ButtonVal+")").show();      

        $("#WebPartWPQ4").find("tr.ms-itmhover:not(:Contains("+txt+"):Contains("+ButtonVal+"))").hide();
        $("#WebPartWPQ4").find("tr.ms-itmhover:Contains("+txt+"):Contains("+ButtonVal+")").show();      

        $("#WebPartWPQ7").find("tr.ms-itmhover:not(:Contains("+txt+"):Contains("+ButtonVal+"))").hide();
        $("#WebPartWPQ7").find("tr.ms-itmhover:Contains("+txt+"):Contains("+ButtonVal+")").show();      

        $("#WebPartWPQ2").find("tr.ms-itmhover:not(:Contains("+txt+"):Contains("+ButtonVal+"))").hide();
        $("#WebPartWPQ2").find("tr.ms-itmhover:Contains("+txt+"):Contains("+ButtonVal+")").show();      

        $("#WebPartWPQ8").find("tr.ms-itmhover:not(:Contains("+txt+"):Contains("+ButtonVal+"))").hide();
        $("#WebPartWPQ8").find("tr.ms-itmhover:Contains("+txt+"):Contains("+ButtonVal+")").show();      
        }
        } search();
        }         }).keyup(function(){$(this).change();

});
```

Comment: Sounds like you want `$("input.search").on('input', function() {...` to catch all input